# unable get data from database cakephp

Tags: cakephp

i want get data from database and calculate the average Rating but when i get data by author id i have message find() is null

this my function

```
public function teacher_average_rating_in_school()

        {



        $this->autoRender = false;

        if($this->request->is('get'))
        {
            $author_id = $this->request->query('author_id');//
            $rate = $this->UserRating->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('author_id'=> $author_id), 'fields'=> array('AVG(UserRating.rstings) as averageRating'), 'recursive' =>-1));

            $average = $rate[0][0]['averageRating'];
            $result = array('success'=>'1' , 'average' => $average );

        }
        else{
            $result = array('success'=>'0','message'=>'request type is not GET');
        }
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

and this my model

class UserRating extends AppModel {

```
public $validate = array(
    'user_id' => array('rule' => 'notBlank'), 'author_id' => array( 'rule' => 'notBlank') ,  array('rstings' => 'notBlank' ));
}
```

why i get find()is null , and how can i solve that ?

Comment: first check is $author_id getting the value then using sql_dump get the query and execute in database directly.so that you will come to know is data present for your condition or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you load the Modal??

```
public function teacher_average_rating_in_school()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
   if($this->request->is('get'))
     {
        $this->loadModel('UserRating');
        $author_id = $this->request->query('author_id');//
        $rate = $this->UserRating->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('author_id'=> $author_id), 'fields'=> array('AVG(UserRating.rstings) as averageRating'), 'recursive' =>-1));

        $average = $rate[0][0]['averageRating'];
        $result = array('success'=>'1' , 'average' => $average );

     }
     else{
        $result = array('success'=>'0','message'=>'request type is not GET');
     }
     echo json_encode($result);
   }
```

If you have already loadModel using then check sql_dump.
You can use as follows

```
//inside controller action
debug($this->UserRating->lastQuery()); 
//Or inside layout call this
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```